"Wallet loading failed: The location of the wallet you previously used has been overwritten (outdated). Now, after fixing the error ..."
An early backup of a Bitcoin wallet .dat is now being restored with the following error message:

Wallet loading failed. The location of the wallet you previously used
has been overwritten (outdated). Now, after fixing the error, you need
to re-index (for already open wallets). Just re-download and update
the new node.


